# Helm where is the value of .node.lifecycle coming from

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, selenium-grid

I am working on selenium grid helm chart and i am trying to understand where does the `.node.lifecycle` is coming from , I don't see it in values.yaml file. is this some how mapped to chrome/firefox/edge node ?

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/charts/selenium-grid/templates/_helpers.tpl#L201C63-L201C63

`{{ $lifecycle := tpl (toYaml (default (dict) .node.lifecycle)) $ }}`

Complete block:

```
{{/*
Get the lifecycle of the pod. When KEDA is activated and the lifecycle is used for a pod of a
deployment preStop hook to deregister from the selenium hub.
*/}}
{{- define "seleniumGrid.lifecycle" }}
{{ $lifecycle := tpl (toYaml (default (dict) .node.lifecycle)) $ }}
{{- if and (eq .Values.autoscaling.scalingType "deployment") (eq (include "seleniumGrid.useKEDA" .) "true") -}}
{{ $lifecycle = merge ($lifecycle | fromYaml ) .Values.autoscaling.deregisterLifecycle | toYaml }}
{{- end -}}
{{ if and $lifecycle (ne $lifecycle "{}") -}}
lifecycle: {{ $lifecycle | nindent 2 }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `.node` is the `chromeNode` etc. which coming from the `$podScope` which defined in each `scaledJob.yml`, for example in `firefox-node-scaledjob.yaml`:

```
{{- $podScope := deepCopy . -}}
{{- $_ := set $podScope "name" "selenium-firefox-node" -}}
{{- $_ =  set $podScope "node" .Values.firefoxNode  -}}
{{- include "seleniumGrid.podTemplate" $podScope | nindent 4 }}
```

So when it's call to `seleniumGrid.podTemplate` it sending the `$podScope` to the `_helpers.tpl` and the variable `seleniumGrid.podTemplate` using it a lot (every time you see `.node`).